# how to display html table in IOS UITextView?

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, uitextview

I have one xml file , that contain html table('sample is attached here'). how can i parse and display to UItextview in ios?

```
<table border = "1"><tr><th title = "Item"></th><th title = "This term:"></th><th title = "is defined in:"></th></tr><tr><td title = "1."></td><td title = "Australian resident"></td><td title = "section 9951"></td></tr><tr><td title = "2."></td><td title = "Commissioner"></td><td title = "section 9951"></td></tr><tr><td title = "3."></td><td title = "company"></td><td title = "section 9951"></td></tr><tr><td title = "4."></td><td title = "entity"></td><td title = "section 960100"></td></tr><tr><td title = "4A."></td><td title = "foreign resident"></td><td title = "section 9951"></td></tr><tr><td title = "5."></td><td title = "individual"></td><td title = "section 9951"></td></tr><tr><td title = "6."></td><td title = "partnership"></td><td title = "section 9951"></td></tr><tr><td title = "7."></td><td title = "person"></td><td title = "section 9951"></td></tr><tr><td title = "8."></td><td title = "trustee"></td><td title = "section 9951"></td></tr><tr><td title = "9."></td><td title = "you"></td><td title = "section 45"></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"YOUR_TABLE_HTML";
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: i want xml parse and load into uitextview.  your directly given a string but the xml also contain lot of things table , paragraph , etc.

Comment: thanks asaf, that example just parsing string and get small paragraph type but i want how to display table format respect string (like html table format).